# How to prepend an element to each list in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I want to prepend a string 'a' to each list in the list such that x becomes:

```
[['a', 1, 2, 3], ['a', 4, 5, 6], ['a', 7, 8, 9]]
```

What is the most pythonic way of achieving this?

What I've got so far:

```
[l.insert(0, 'a') for l in x]
```

Comment: If you need to prepend items, considering using a `collections.deque` instead of a `list`. Prepending is O(1) for deques, but O(n) for lists.

Comment: By the way, don't use a list comprehension just for the side effect of `l.insert`. Use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just concat what you want to prepend:

```
[['a'] + l for l in x]

# [['a', 1, 2, 3], ['a', 4, 5, 6], ['a', 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Note this has different semantics; whereas `l.insert(0, 'a')` mutates an existing list, this creates new lists in their place.

Comment: @chepner I thought about that as well, but there's not much reason (that I could imagine) to insert in place if we can `x = [['a' + l for l in x]`.  Barring the possibility that perhaps the lists are horrendously huge... Then a `for loop` would be better.  I'm not savvy with the `deque` usage though so yours is a nice alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Prepending to a list is expensive (O(n)), because you need to move every element of the list to make room for the new item. (Appending, by contrast, is cheap.)

If this is something you need to do often for these lists, consider using a `deque` instead, which is optimized to support appending and prepending efficiently.

```
from collections import deque

x = [deque([1,2,3]), deque([4,5,6]), deque([7,8,9])]
for d in x:
    d.appendleft('a')
```